# Some thing about JS error in starting a Ruby Server on Win7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

---

### UPDATE +2 hrs:

I rebooted, uninstalled, and then installed a new copy of the downloaded Railsinstaller program.

Pulled the gem marble down, and installed it. Said it installed correctly. (However, I think I read at some places that just gem name is sufficient and gem install name is redundant.)

Started the server - same problem. Runtime JS doesn't exist.

So I created a new app. Build went through clean. Installed the execjs again. (Installed correctly). The ran 'rails s' and the same exact problem persists.

Solution not found.

---

I'm an absolute newbie. Sequence of steps:

1. Installed Ruby the traditional way. Download from Ruby website, install, try to make it work. Something went wrong - the BUNDLE INSTALL said it couldn't find a gem file.

I said no problem - let's search for answers...

1. I installed Railsinstaller as the full package. Installation went well. I even created a new dummy app called 'my_app'.

Yay...

1. Then I navigated to the directory with the app and punched 'rails s' on the command prompt (Which by the way is being run as administrator)

The server started (WEBrick). 
I go to localhost:3000 and nothing shows. 
I go to prompt and do gem install rails 
It goes and fetches some gems and does some more work

Now when I start the server - it throws some error about Javascript.

Here's the error:

C:\Sites\my_app>rails s

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:50:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-
2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3
.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3
.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Sites\my_app>
```

I have no idea what to do next. Please help...

Comment: Did you visit the link mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

My Hosts file was filled with some validator crap. Cleaned that out and the server is working now.